# Prevent automatic zoom on location found event in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, vue.js

I have created the beginnings of a web app which will track locations in real time. It's all working, but every time the location updates, the zoom level refreshes to something that seems pre-defined. I would like the user to manually choose a zoom level (using the touchscreen) which will then stay at that level with each new location update (until the user changes it again).

```
var marker;
var circle;
var map;
onMounted(() => {
    map = L.map("mapContainer").fitWorld();
    L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        maxZoom: 19,
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
    map.locate({setView: true, watch: true, maxZoom: 19});
})
onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    if (map) {
      map.remove();
    }
  })

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy;

    if (marker)
      map.removeLayer(marker);
    if (circle)
      map.removeLayer(circle);
    marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
     //   .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    circle = L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Culprit for the described behavior is `setView: true` option when initiating locate with the `map.locate` method. If you look at the docs at https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#locate-options you can read for `setView: true` option:

> If true, automatically sets the map view to the user location with
> respect to detection accuracy, or to world view if geolocation failed.

So what you have to do is to leave this option out and set view center yourselves in the `onLocationFound` function.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
map.locate({
  watch: true,
  maxZoom: 19
});

function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy;
  if (marker) map.removeLayer(marker);
  if (circle) map.removeLayer(circle);
  marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
  circle = L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
  map.panTo(e.latlng);
}
```

Comment: Nearly correct, thanks. Actually I needed to add an `onZoom` event handler and set `desiredZoom` in that. If you can edit your answer to reflect that, I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: I did not understand your question the way you meant it. See modified answer. That works without necessity to have `onZoom` handler.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you create a new marker every time.

Try to set the geometry of your marker.

```
# create a marker  
var m = L.marker([50.4,9.6]).addTo(map);

# on an event (in my example on button click)
document.getElementById("mm").onclick = function() {

  # get the marker position
  var ll = m.getLatLng();

  # change it
  ll.lat = ll.lat + 0.01;

  # update the marker position
  m.setLatLng(ll);

 # you can probably just write
 # m.setLatLng(e.latlng);
 # inside your event handler
};
```

See fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/q07t2gpz/ .

Note how only one marker object is created and added to the map and re-used every time the location changes, as opposed to your code example where you create a new marker every time and add the new marker to the map.

edit: I updated the fiddle, see https://jsfiddle.net/L45pucj2/ , and added a button to get the geolocation. The relevant function is

```
document.getElementById("loc").onclick = function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    m.setLatLng([pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude]);
  });
};
```

Thus, I think you neet to change your onLocationFound function like this:

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
    if (!marker) {
      # init the marker to 0,0 on the first call
      marker = L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map);
    }
    marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
}
```

The mention of setView by @TomazicM still applies!

I have created a comprehensive fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/L45pucj2/1/ where you can observe the effect of setView on the zoom settings.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I can see your 'fiddle' working (with a 'manual' update of location) but it doesn't work with the auto update created by the `watch` option. I also removed the circle to see if that was causing the problem - but to no avail